# How To Add Remote Control Box In Ceiling Fan

Tags: ceiling-fan

I recently purchased a new ceiling fan that has a box that the remote control will connect to and control lights/fan speed.  In the instructions for the fan it says to place the box above the mounting bracket and inside of the mounting box.  However, there isn't enough space to add the remote box.  So I'm not sure what options I have to hide the remote box under the fan housing.

Anyone here experienced something similar and have ideas?

Below are images of the box as well as the ceiling mount.

[image: Remote Box]

[image: electrical box]

Comment: What all is in the ceiling box?  Should just be a couple of wires/wire nuts.  The couple of fans like that that I've fooled with, you could usually make room for the control box by moving the wires around.

Comment: And, are you sure you have the mounting bracket installed correctly?  If it's upside down, it would protrude into the space the box is supposed to go.

Comment: can we have  picture

Comment: This is not uncommon. Try again, but with all the wire connections pushed up into the junction box. This is usually tough to do.

Answer (score 2):

The box is supposed to slide into the slot that is in the middle of the fan bracket. The slot is visible in your second photo. You'll need to move the wiring as far into the upper part of the box as possible, then slide the control box in and arrange the remainder of the wiring so it won't interfere with the cover. Then install the cover.
It's often quite tricky to do this, keep trying.

Comment: ohhh, so if I push all the wiring into the electrical box in the cieling there will be space for the "control"?  Any tips on how to do it?  If it's tricky to do, i can keep on trying, just wanted to make sure it is/was possible before i had something FUBAR

Comment: I usually try to connect the box to the ceiling wires before installing the bracket, then carefully put the wiring into the box and route it so it won't get pinched when installing the bracket. Then install the bracket, slide the box in, and make the fan connections. Some fans have a little hook you can use to hold it up temporarily while you're doing this - make sure you make use of this, or have a helper to hold it up.

Comment: ahhh, this is one where there is an opening in the mounting bracket and you have to slide the "ball" from the fan into it to mount.  I might take it down and try to see if that makes a diffference or easy for me

Comment: I think part of my problem is that the electrical box is not properly secured to a stud in the cieling....the box wiggles way to much and the sheet rock on the cieling is starting to flake away....i'll take it all down and attempt to connect the remote box before the mounting bracket this time.

Comment: @user2676140 -- that's a *bad* sign -- I suspect the original box was never fan rated and is starting to fail, so you need to replace it with a fan rated box

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel - wow, I didn't know there was a "fan rated box" - is this something my local hardware store would have?  (pretty standard thing)

Comment: Yes, hardware store should have it, and your local big home improvement store would have it for sure also.

Answer (score 1):

I had this exact same problem and what we found was that the ball hanger was supposed to be sitting in a groove in the bracket (once it's in place it won't spin freely anymore, and it drops a fraction of an inch lower giving enough clearance for the receiver to sit without interfering). I was about to take an angle grinder to mine to make a channel for the excess wire. Glad I didn't go to that length.